# How many bits are in a Bitcoin?

Tags: development

I need to track an amount of Bitcoins in a database.  Is a UINT64 sufficient?

I'd rather not deal with floating point types, and the rounding errors they end with.

Comment: The title is catchy but nonsensical.  I am guessing you are trying to keep track of an *amount* of bitcoins (e.g. BTC 3.01329) but that is not clear from your wording

Comment: @NateEldredge it's tagged development, yes..  I want to know that the max value in a Tx is defined to be 64 bits. I made it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, UINT64 is sufficient, which is in fact how the Bitcoin protocol works internally. The conversion factor from UINT64 to BTC is 1.0e8.

Not using floating point numbers is a very good idea indeed.